# Novatec Hub D041SB and Novatec Hub D042SB What's the difference?

Tags: mountain-bike

I dont understand what is D041SB and D042SB can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little worried I might be missing something, but 41 is a front and 42 is a rear.

Comment: https://img.joomcdn.net/2ab9925c03840a8d893fc9979407196525a2e119_original.jpeg  would support this difference.